# how to add filter extension to a file upload in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Validate the File Type of a File Upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944/how-do-i-validate-the-file-type-of-a-file-upload)

i would like to add file extension for filtering to file upload control in my asp.net page.and do validation on client side.

how can i set file extension dynamically..

ex:images only(*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;).

Comment: The question was asked - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944/how-do-i-validate-the-file-type-of-a-file-upload/72221#72221

Answer (score 0):

in Properties pane>Filter> "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"

or 
object.Filter("txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*");