# how to read word document before uploading it by webpage

Tags: asp.net

I have excel file abc.xls and I renamed it as abc.doc using command prompt.
My requirement is: I want to upload a proper doc file, but there I can only check the MIME type of the file to upload file, this is not sufficient. I want to confirm  before uploading the doc file, that it is a doc and not allow users to upload abc.doc file, because it is not a doc file its a excel file.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/71944/745359

Comment: Why you need client-side validation? If you don't trust the input you have to check it on the server again. What about the solution outlined in the question I linked?

Comment: what happened if I open the uploaded file which is actually excel not a doc file, it will give error like corrupted file when trying to open in ms word. So I am trying to avoid this future problem.

Comment: You are wrong as to where validation should happen. This is a core webprogramming Principle: Always validate on the server side! See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because the OP wrote it in the comments:

You are on a wrong track here, Validation should always happen on the server side, you can add additional validation on the client side, but its not required. You have to do this for a simple reason:

Clients can always circumvent client-side Validation methods because the Client is fully under their control. So even if you implement your validation method to check if its a doc or excel document, a bad user can always just send you a post request with the validation disabled and you're getting a excel document or a virus etc.

This is a core webprogramming principle: **Never trust input data**, you can't validate on the client only!

Secondly your validation is done much mor easily on the server. So you should upload any file (check for file extensions & size) and then validate on the server!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an ActiveX Object to access the file content on the client system before uploading. Checking the byte array with javascript to find whether it's a real doc might prove interesting though :-)
**EDIT :**

```
function CheckWordDoc(filepath){
    var fso, f, ts, s;
    var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8;
    var TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    f = fso.getFile(filepath);
    ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault);
    while (!ts.AtEndOfStream) {
        s = ts.ReadLine();
        if (s.indexOf("Word.Document.8") != -1) {
            ts.Close( );
            return true;
        }
    }          
    ts.Close( );
    return false;
}
```

http://www.piclist.com/techref/language/asp/vbs/vbscript/jsmthopenastextstream.htm
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfw5c59%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: from the size we can't decide this is proper doc file

Comment: I know. That's why I said it will be interesting to check the byte array whether it's a real doc file...old doc file appear to have something like "Word.Document.8" at the end. docx file are compressed xml having occasional "word/" text defining the nodes...But ActiveX is blocked by default nowadays on most browsers, so I REALLY recommend uploading the file and check the bytes on the server before saving it to the disk.