# jQuery validation - required working but accept not

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

im uploading an image and trying to validate it before with jquery. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#message_box", wrapper: "li",

        rules: {
            image: {required: true, accept: "jpg|jpeg|png|gif"}
        },
        messages: {
            image: {required: 'Required!', accept: 'Not an image!'}
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Required is working - if i insert no image i get an error. But accept isn't working (anything i insert passes) and i cant figure out why. Any ideas? :)

Comment: you don't need jQuery..seems like you are using 99.9% code you don't need just to make a simple test to see if a field is "required" and if the file type if valid..just do that. also, you can also check with JS if the file was an actual image or not - http://stackoverflow.com/q/71944/104380 also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/181214/104380

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need two things.

**(1)** use valid syntax for using `accept` method because it requires you to use to provide comma-separated list of mimetypes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#message_box", wrapper: "li",

        rules: {
            image: {required: true, accept: "image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif"}
        },
        messages: {
            image: {required: 'Required!', accept: 'Not an image!'}
        }
    })
});
```

**(2)** You'll have to include the `additional-methods.js` because the `accept` methods is not included in the core validate plugin. So add following to your `<head>` after you include validate plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the **[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TJWQV/)**. Note that it includes `debug: true` to prevent posting of the form in fiddle.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer.  However, the easiest fix is to change `accept` into `extension`.  See [`extension`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension) rule.

Comment: jquery validation error "<<uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'call' of undefined>>"...i get this error thanks for your answer ...

Answer (score 6):

1) As already stated, you need to include the `additional-methods.js` file.

2) For file extensions, use [the `extension` rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension).  The `accept` rule is for mime types.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#form").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#message_box", wrapper: "li",
        rules: {
            image: {
                required: true,
                extension: "jpg|jpeg|png|gif"
            }
        },
        ...
    })

});
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept) states that the `accept` rule only accepts mime-types as an argument.

If you wanted to accept all images then use `image/*`.

If you want to accept only specific image types then you can specify multiple mime-types by separating them with a comma, e.g. `image/pjpeg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif`.